# xml filtering attribute

Tags: xml

i tried to write an xslt template match that will choose all of the product that is not item="toy".below is my code but its not working can i know what may be the error?

```
  <color>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//product/@item[not(.='toy')]">
  </color>
```

Comment: Might this be a namespace problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your XML and XSLT, although some may be typos when you created your question. Your XML is lacking a namespace declaration for **xsi** and your apply-templates is using double-quotes instead of single quotes. It is also unclosed.

However, the real problem is that you say you watch to select the **product** nodes, but your apply-templates is actually trying to select the actual **item** attribute.

Try this instead

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//product[not(@xsi:item='toy')]" />
```

Or maybe this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//product[@xsi:item!='toy']" />
```

Comment: have tested on ur way, and the name space issue for <xsl:template match="//product[@xsi:item!='toy']" />  is still there.

Comment: ok i found the problem, i forgot to declare the prefix for my new template match.thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with single quotes:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//product/@xsi:item[not(.='toy')]">
```